# how to put Image on JPanel using Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, imageicon

And how do I put Image on a JPanel using Netbeans?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at this tutorial: [Handling Images in a Java GUI Application](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-image-display.html)

At the same time you could code as well:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(); 
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("image.jpg"); 
JLabel label = new JLabel(); 
label.setIcon(icon); 
panel.add(label);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use ImageIcon and JLabel:

```
ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("image.gif", "sample image");

// Label with text and icon
JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Image and Text", icon, JLabel.CENTER);

// Label with icon only
JLabel label2 = new JLabel(icon);

// Add to your JPanel
panel.add(label1);
panel.add(label2);
```

Answer (score 2):

1) First Paste the image to the Application folder
2) Add a label to the panel
3) Right click label-> Properties
4) Select Icon-> more option
5) Select Package and File and Click oK
6) U R DONE :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a JLabel with your icon property set to the picture.
 For a more detailed solution to the particular problem, go to

http://www.netbeanstutorials.com/p/handling-images.html

There's even a video how to do it there in case you need it.